# Move between nested switches in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My application has nested switches and I am trying to work out how to create a link that will navigate from one to the other. The app is structured like this:

```
App
  Main switch (/)
    Assets switch (/assets/)
      Table component with Link
    Templates switch (/templates/)
      Object viewer component to be linked too
```

The link component looks like this, with id being the templates UUID:

```
<Link to={`/templates/${id}`} {...itemProps} />
```

But when you click the link you go to /assets/correct-UUID.

I can't find any information on this so I'm not sure if this is the classic intermediate problem not covered by tutorials, something that isn't possible or I'm just doing something wrong. Does anyone know which one it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That defeats the purpose of the Switch and the router at the same time. From the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/):

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

Switch basically ensures there's only ever one component rendered in the router. For optimal results, keep your routes in one component, as there is rarely any need to nest them like you do. For example:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router'

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Main}/>
  <Route path="/assets" component={Assets}/>
  <Route path="/templates" component={Templates}/>
</Switch>
```

So you define your routes in your app entry point let's say `App.js`. And that's it, if you want more routes, add them there. If you want nested routes, you nest by literally nesting it: `<Route path="/assets/:id/update" component={AssetUpdate} />`. That's all there is to it.